# Evaluating the Nullity of Linear Transformation $T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $T$ is a Linear Transformation from $\mathbb{R^5} \to \mathbb{R^{5}}$ such that

$T^2 = 0$ if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$ then show that

$T(x,y,z,0,0) = (0,0,0,0,0)$

Since $T^2 =0$   ;  $\text{Rank T} \le \text{Nullity T}$ Now using Rank Nullity theorem I get

Rank T $\le  5/2$ at this point I am stuck  I don't know how can I use the condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1 $ to prove the given result.

Can anyone please help me here ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by:
$$
 "\mbox{$T^2 = 0$ if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$}"?
$$
Does this mean that $\ T^2(x,y,z,w,v)=(0,0,0,0,0)\ $ for all $\ (x,y,z,w,v)\ $ such that $\ x^2+y^2+z^2=1\ $?

Comment: Well,this question is from a book and I reproduced the question as written in there,In the book it has not been mentioned anything extra other than this.But your observation must be correct because we are dealing with R^5 and so  it must be (x,y,z,w,v).

Comment: The problem is that if that's what is meant (and I can't see what else it might have been intended to mean) then the conclusion isn't true.  If
$$
T(x,y,z,w,v) = (z,0,0,0,0)
$$
then $\ T(x,y,1,0,0,0)=(1,0,0,0,0)\ne (0,0,0,0,0)\ $, even though $\ T^2=0\ $.